# Resuming Chrome file download after shutting down the PC

Tags: google-chrome, download

I have initiated a large download. Unfortunately, internet is slower than usual, and this download will take 3 more hours. I need to leave in 1 hour, and need to shut down the PC. Is there some way that I can freeze this download and resume it later? If I suspend/hibernate, will this continue? Or should I pause it with the built-in Chrome function, and then somehow copy the temporary files and kill / close Chrome, and put this back in place after turning it on again?

Using Chrome 18 on Linux.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pause it with the option built-in to Chrome, and hibernate the computer.  If the SERVER that is providing the download supports resuming downloads, then after you resume from hibernation, you should have no issues resuming the download.

After you pause the download, there is no need to touch Chrome.  Just pause, and hibernate.  By that I mean, don't close Chrome.  Don't kill it or edit anything.  Just pause the download, leave Chrome up and running, and hibernate.

Comment: Ultimately, my internet connection simply failed before I could do this, so this issue was "solved" beforehand. I'm marking this as accepted because I think this would have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to hibernate the computer. If you just use a download manager such as [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/download/index) (multiplatform) you'll be able to resume the download after shutdown provided the server you are downloading from supports it.

Some websites, due to server software, just do not support resuming downloads and they can't start transmitting midway through a file.

Comment: This works with files that are already in the process of being downloaded?  Meaning in the example provided by the OP, since he has almost finished the download, if he were to now install JDownloader, it would assume control of the download in progress and allow for it to be continued later?  Or would using JDownload only apply to downloads started after it has been installed?

Comment: Only after it had been installed - good point +1

Comment: I've used JDownloader and Mipony for years. They are great, I use them especially to download from sites such as rapidgator, nitroflare.... Problem is they come in with lots of Ads and I believe they're also mining stuff or doing other things under the cover.

Answer (score 0):

Just pause the download before shutting down your computer. When you turn it back on you only have to resume it in the download section (in settings or press CRTL-J). It takes a while to restart and might not work for every download but it worked for me, hope it helps future users!

Answer (score 0):

I own a laptop and I use VMs often. So when I download large files like macOS Catalina ISOs, I let it continue the download and just put it on sleep mode, making sure that the air vent is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

there is one way you can use if the server does not support pausing the download
you have to go to the download page then disconnect your wifi wait for 5 minutes then put it on again once its on it should say download failed (dont worry it didnt fail) then when you press resume it should resume even if the server doesnt support pausing

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will allow resuming if you terminate it's process via task manager. If you close it normally, chrome will cancel the download.

Answer (score 0):

you only need simple trick:

1. trun of your wifi
2. if download fail don't click continue
3. trun off your pc and start again
4. open chrome>download/ctrl+j
5. click continue
6. DONE

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already got well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way but it will work only in some apps.

1. Download a file in Chrome web browser.
2. Go to *Chrome Downloads*.
3. Wait for a few seconds.
4. Now without closing your browser just shut down your computer without pausing it or closing your browser.
5. Now switch off your UPS and open plug. After a few minutes reopen your computer and open browser -> Chrome Downloads.
6. Click on Resume or Retry.
7. If it does not start or starts from beginning, then go to the first line of my answer. It could work only in some apps.