# Resume interrupted downloads in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Recently, I was downloading a 3GB .iso file using Chrome's inbuilt download manager when I accidentally switched off my UPS. When I switched on my computer, it told that the download was interupted and when I clicked retry it started downloading again. I had already downloaded 1.8 GB. I do not want to download the file from the beginning again.

Is there any way to resume this download?

PS: I am using Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'll leave this here for others too.  It is perfectly okay, you don't have to restart the download.  Just open Chromium, and type:

```
chrome://downloads
```

It will show you new/old downloads, and maybe a `Network interrupted` error, but there should be a resume button.  Click that, wait a few seconds, and it should resume downloading.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

After doing some research, I found out that the following method works.

1. Start downloading the file in Firefox and pause it.
2. Rename the chrome download "1315.iso.crdownload" to "1315.iso.part".
3. Replace the .part file in the Firefox download folder with the renamed file.
4. Resume the download in Firefox.

Firefox will automatically start downloading from where you left off. Also, it may be preferable to use a download manager to avoid these sort of incidences.

You can also do it using [wget](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/interrupted-download-heres-how-to-resume-in-chrome/).

PS: If you have a download manager, you will have to temporarily switch off browser integration for Firefox.

[Video Instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cgs628bZD_8)

Comment: Why did you post a solution that applies to Firefox instead of Chrome?

Comment: @Ramhound Because there was no way to resume the download in Chrome. The download has cross-compatibility so what you started in Chrome you can finish in Firefox, but not the other way around. According to me, Chrome has a pretty antique download manager.

Comment: Except it is [possible](http://superuser.com/questions/420316/resuming-chrome-file-download-after-shutting-down-the-pc?rq=1) to do this without using another browser to do it

Comment: @Ramhound But that only works if Chrome is kept on and Hibernation is used. I am talking about a full shut down. When you close Chrome, it doesn't give the ability to start again.

Comment: Your question didn't indicate that...

Comment: @Ramhound When I said that I accidentally pressed the power button of my ups I meant that the computer got switched off. also, even if you pause and exit the download will get stopped.